# Is it possible to have memory mapped messages in ROS?

Tags: ros, ros-comm, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sending huge messages like images over a pipe can slow things down a lot.
Is there a way we can have memory mapped messages in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9100/is-it-possible-to-have-memory-mapped-messages-in-ros?/) by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2011-02-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been discussed several times. A partial implementation of shared memory message passing was implemented as an experiment.

It turns out that the main overhead is serializing and deserializing the data, not copying the bytes. The shared memory transport still incurs that, so the speed-up was disappointing.

A better solution for high throughput applications is using [nodelets](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nodelet), which allow zero-copy transport within a single address space while still providing standard ROS message semantics to nodes in other processes or machines.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9